# Mapping JSON fields

Tags: javascript, json, mapping

I have a JSON created with PHP json_encode function:

```
$json = [{"title":"test1","date":"2019, 12, 27"},{"title":"test2","date":"2019, 11, 19"}];
```

I want to map these fields into calendar dataSource fields: https://year-calendar.github.io/rc-year-calendar/examples How to do this properly?

What I need:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
const calendar = new Calendar('#calendar', {
  dataSource: [
            {
                startDate: new Date(2019, 12, 27),
                name: 'test1'
            },
            {
                startDate: new Date(2019, 11, 19),
                name: 'test2'
            }, 
        ],
});
</script>
```

What I tried:

```
$json = [{"title":"test1","date":"2019, 12, 27"},{"title":"test2","date":"2019, 11, 19"}];

<script type="text/javascript">

var json = <?php echo $json; ?>;
const calendar = new Calendar('#calendar', {
  dataSource: [
          return json.map(r => ({
            startDate: new Date(r.date),
            name: r.title,
          }));
        ],
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```js
const calendarArray = [{"title":"test1","date":"2019, 12, 27"},{"title":"test2","date":"2019, 11, 19"}];


const dataSource = calendarArray.map((element) => {
  return {
    startDate: new Date(element.date),
    name: element.title
  }
});

const calendar = new Calendar("#calendar", {dataSource: dataSource})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/js-year-calendar@latest/dist/js-year-calendar.min.js"></script>
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use map inside an array. .map() returns creates a new array of values based on an original array. You are defining data source as an array and are trying to use it like a function, which is why it's not working

Try this

```
    const calendarData = json.map(r => ({
            startDate: new Date(r.date),
            name: r.title,
          }));
    const calendar = new Calendar('#calendar', {
    dataSource: calendarData
});
```

Or in line

```
const calendar = new Calendar('#calendar', {
  dataSource: json.map(r => ({
            startDate: new Date(r.date),
            name: r.title,
          }));,
        });
```